# Getting INT value from class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC site that i am trying to edit.

New to C# and MVC

I have a class like this

```
public partial class MultipackInstruction
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Multipack { get; set; }

    [StringLength(7)]
    public string Line { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the values for this to make links to edit each item

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <span>@item.Text</span>  
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditInstruction", "Mods",  new { id = item.Id, id2 = item.Multipack, id3 = item.Text, id4 = item.CduId, id5 = item.Id, id6 = item.Line}, null) <br />
}
```

The above code is included in this in the view

```
<div class="col-lg-12">

<h4>Multipack : @Model.Multipack</h4>
<h4>Requested Date :    @(Model.DateOfRequest.HasValue ? Model.DateOfRequest.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "")</h4>
<h4>Information :   </h4>
@if (Model.ManagedInstructionList != null)
{

        @Html.Partial("_ManageInstructionList", Model.ManagedInstructionList)

}
```

I have only added all variables for testing all i need to use is the individual Id for each item.

Problem i have is the class is returning values for everything for each item in the class except for the Int Id which is returning 0 for each item

Is this to do with it being a Int and not a string like all other values?

Or am i missing something

thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with it being an `int`.

Comment: Did you assigned value to `id` in your view?

Comment: Non-nullable `int` has default value of 0 and it's normal to have it in unassigned `int` property.

Comment: SeM cant see a value set anywhere and Tetsuya Yamamoto can you explain some more please are you saying the int is unassigned if so what do i do to fix as it is in database and coded same as all other variables i am accesing

Comment: @ColinO'Donoghue You really need to learn about basics of asp .net mvc.

Answer (score 1):

you probably don't set any value for your `Id`, and because this is non-nullable, it returns the default value of `int`, mean 0.

Comment: Is there an easy way to change this i know its set in database to not null as its the identity column? thanks

Comment: are you change "id" column to auto-identity now ?!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this Hamed

Comment: Auto-increment(Identity) allows a unique number to be generated automatically when a new record is inserted into a table. Often this is the primary key field (in your case is Id) that we would like to be created automatically every time a new record is inserted.

in my opnion you must read more about basics. 
good luck ;)

Comment: OK so no its not an auto increment ID

Comment: Sorry just re read this and every entry in database has a value set fir the Id

Comment: So, your Id value is auto-identity ... Please send your controller code and complete view code ...

Answer (score 0):

Modify this portion into `MultipackInstruction` Class

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```